# Why Swift using subscript syntax in a for-in loops is faster than using direct access to the element?

Tags: swift, performance, optimization, branch-prediction

I read the famous [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array) and I decided to play around and experiment with other languages such as Swift. I was surprised by the run time differences between 2 very similar snippets of code.

In Swift one can access elements in an array either in a direct way or with a subscript while in a for-in loop. For instance this code:

```
for i in 0..<size {
    sum += data[i]
}
```

Could be written:

```
for element in data {
    sum += element
}
```

With `size` the `data` length and `data` an array of summable elements.

So, I just implemented in Swift (code bellow) the same algorithm as in the question I mentioned in the first paragraph and what surprised me is that the first method is roughly 5 times faster than the second method.

I don't really know the backstage subscript implementation but I thought that accessing directly the elements in a Swift for-in loop was just syntactic sugar.

---

### Question

My question is what is the difference between the two `for-in` syntaxes and why it is faster to use subscript?

here is the detail of timers. I'm using Xcode 9.4.1 with Swift 4.1 on an early 2015 MacBook Air with a Commande Line Project.

```
// Using Direct Element Access
Elapsed Time: 8.506288427
Sum: 1051901000
```

vs

```
// Using Subscript
Elapsed Time: 1.483967902
Sum: 1070388000
```

**Bonus question**: why the execution is 100 times slower in Swift than in C++ (both executed on the same Mac in a n Xcode project)? For instance 100,000 repetitions in C++ take nearly the same time as 1,000 repetitions in Swift. My first guess is that Swift is a higher level language than C++ and that Swift operates more safety checks for instance.

---

Here is the Swift code I used, I only modified the second nested loop:

```
import Foundation
import GameplayKit

let size = 32_768
var data = [Int]()
var sum  = 0
var rand = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 0, highestValue: 255)

for _ in 0..<size {
    data.append(rand.nextInt())
}

// data.sort()

let start = DispatchTime.now()

for _ in 0..<1_000 {
    // Only the following for-in loop changes
    for i in 0..<size {
        if data[i] <= 128 {
            sum += data[i]
        }
    }
}

let stop     = DispatchTime.now()
let nanoTime = stop.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds
let elapsed  = Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000_000

print("Elapsed Time: \(elapsed)")
print("Sum: \(sum)")
```

Comment: Were you testing in a Swift playground or a compiled app?

Comment: I'm using a compiled app (commande line project).

Comment: I suspect you're not compiling with optimizations. With `-O`, I'm seeing about a 10% cost at most, not 10x. Also you'd need to compare to `-Ounchecked` if you're comparing to C++.

Comment: Unless you use `-0unchecked`, every basic arithmetic operation does a branch (if checks for overflow, and crashes rather than allowing overflown results to be used)

Comment: Ok @RobNapier, I got the same result as you with `-O`. So to sum up when unoptimized the second loop method is far slower than using subscript.

Comment: @LouisLac Performance tests are pointless unless you're making optimized builds. The default settings are there for developer convenience (fast compile times, debug symbols) not run-time performance. Iteration in a for loop involves multiple function calls (`Sequence.makeIterator(), IteratorProtocol.next()`), that would slow things down if they're not optimized out (which they are, in `-O`)

Comment: Ok great I better understand how all this works together, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The overall performance output highly depends on the optimizations done by the compiler. If you compile your code with optimizations enabled, you will see the difference between both solutions is minimal.

To demonstrate this, I updated your code adding two methods, one with `subscripting` and the other using `for-in`.

```
import Foundation
import GameplayKit

let size = 32_768
var data = [Int]()
var sum  = 0
var rand = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 0, highestValue: 255)

for _ in 0..<size {
    data.append(rand.nextInt())
}

// data.sort()

func withSubscript() {
  let start = DispatchTime.now()

  for _ in 0..<1_000 {
      for i in 0..<size {
          if data[i] <= 128 {
              sum += data[i]
          }
      }
  }

  let stop    = DispatchTime.now()
  let elapsed = Double(stop.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds) / 1_000_000_000

  print("With subscript:")
  print("- Elapsed Time: \(elapsed)")
  print("- Sum: \(sum)")
}

func withForIn() {
  let start = DispatchTime.now()

  for _ in 0..<1_000 {
      for element in data {
          if element <= 128 {
              sum += element
          }
      }
  }

  let stop    = DispatchTime.now()
  let elapsed = Double(stop.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds) / 1_000_000_000

  print("With for-in:")
  print("- Elapsed Time: \(elapsed)")
  print("- Sum: \(sum)")
}

withSubscript()
withForIn()
```

I saved that code into a file called `array-subscripting.swift`.

Then, from the command line, we can run it without any optimizations, like this:

```
$ swift array-subscripting.swift 
With subscript:
- Elapsed Time: 0.924554249
- Sum: 1057062000
With for-in:
- Elapsed Time: 5.796038213
- Sum: 2114124000
```

As you mentioned in the post, there is a big difference in performance.

This difference is pretty negligible when the code is compiled with optimizations:

```
$ swiftc array-subscripting.swift -O
$ ./array-subscripting 
With subscript:
- Elapsed Time: 0.110622556
- Sum: 1054578000
With for-in:
- Elapsed Time: 0.11670454
- Sum: 2109156000
```

As you can see, both solutions are way faster than before, and very similar on time execution.

Back to your original question, `subscripting` provides direct access to memory, which is pretty efficient in the case of contiguous arrays, where elements are stored next to each other in memory.

`for-in` loops, in the other hand, create an immutable copy of each element from the array, which incurs in a performance hit.

Comment: ehm, you should set `sum` to `0` before running every method. It took me same time to understand why your two sums are not the same.

Comment: Haha, yeah. I doubt that would have any impact on the result, but you are correct, I missed that.

Comment: Ok it wasn't clear for me that for-in loops create immutable copy while subscripting is just a way to access memory. That the answer I wanted, thanks!

Comment: You an also do `for var` if you want to create a mutable copy.